# NFS mount share from Linux AD authentication to Linux with NIS authentication

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, linux-networking

I have two machines:

1. Linux with AD authentication and running NFS server
2. Linux with NIS authentication

Problem:

When I try to mount any share from first machine (AD authentication) to second (NIS authentication) I always get somehing like this 
drwxrws---+ 13 16777260 16777222 4096 Sep 21 09:42 software

In fact I can't access to this folder because on NIS machine I don't have the user with such UID/GID

Question:

May somebody know how resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The NFS Server on the windows machine is translating the AD Users to *nix user ID's.
You will need to reconfigure the NFS Server on windows for proper translation of the *nix users.

This document should be your starting point to configure the NFS server.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782783%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look at but my NFS server based on Linux

Answer (score 0):

The `nfsd` man page states:

> nfsd  bases  its  access control to files on the server machine on the
>   uid and gid provided in each NFS RPC request. The normal behavior a
>   user would expect is that she can access her files on the server just
>   as she would on a normal file system. **This requires that the same
>   uids and gids  are used on the client and the server machine.**

Unfortunately, NFS can't map users (except to anonymous/nobody with options `root_squash`/`all_squash`, that is).

I see two possible ways to get around this problem:

1) Create a NIS group with GID 16777222 and add the NIS users who need access to the NFS filesystem to that NIS group.

2) Or, if the GID of the NIS group isn't in use on the NFS server and NFS supports ACLs, you could use ACLs to give the requested access to the NIS group (I assume readwrite access, for read-only access drop the 'w' in `setfacl` below). Assuming a directory called "software", do this on the NFS server:

```
# Back up current ACLs to /tmp/acls
getfacl -R -p --access /full/path/to/software > /tmp/acls
# Set default ACL rwx for new created directories
find /full/path/to/software -type d -exec setfacl -m d:g:<gid nis group>:rwx {} \;
# Set ACL rwx recursively in existing directories
find /full/path/to/software -type d -exec setfacl -m g:<gid nis group>:rwx {} \;
# Set ACL rwx recursively in existing files
find /full/path/to/software ! -type d -exec setfacl -m g:<gid nis group>:rw {} \;
```

[I recommend you to **test** the above procedure first. Create a directory, set ACLs, export it and test it.]

`<gid nis group>` is the GID of the NIS group. You don't need to add the NIS GID to `/etc/groups` on the NFS server. Obviously, if not added then you must specify the GID above as a numeric value.

Notice that `setfacl` can also recursively apply ACLs with the option -R. I prefer to use `find` and specifically set rwx for directories and rw for files.

If anything goes wrong:

```
# Flush ACLs
setfacl -R -b /full/path/to/software
# Restore ACLs
setfacl --restore=/tmp/acls
```